# Difficulty to find out meaning of this block of code?

Tags: php, obfuscation

I was decrypting a malware and after that, I find a block of an array in PHP code that I cannot understand how it works, I need your expert opinion on this matter.

```
$s=array("w"=>"e","t"=>"c","l"=>"a","r"=>"m","q"=>".","@"=>"t","e"=>"s","c"=>"@","v"=>"g","h"=>"i","y"=>"l","u"=>"o");
$dash=$s['e'].$s['t'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['q'].$s['@'].$s['w'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['c'].$s['v'].$s['r'].$s['l'].$s['h'].$s['y'].$s['q'].$s['t'].$s['u'].$s['r'];
```

The total block of code is:

```
<?php
$s=array("w"=>"e","t"=>"c","l"=>"a","r"=>"m","q"=>".","@"=>"t","e"=>"s","c"=>"@","v"=>"g","h"=>"i","y"=>"l","u"=>"o");
$dash=$s['e'].$s['t'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['q'].$s['@'].$s['w'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['c'].$s['v'].$s['r'].$s['l'].$s['h'].$s['y'].$s['q'].$s['t'].$s['u'].$s['r'];
if ($action=="send"){
  if (!$from && !$subject && !$message && !$emaillist){
    print "Please complete all fields before sending your message.";
    exit;
```

This is part of a block of code that was appended to "**contact us**" page.

Comment: It's simpler than you think... it's just defining an array then using string concatenation to create the `$dash` string. This one appears to encode an email address "scam.team@gmail.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$s=array("w"=>"e","t"=>"c","l"=>"a","r"=>"m","q"=>".","@"=>"t","e"=>"s","c"=>"@","v"=>"g","h"=>"i","y"=>"l","u"=>"o");
$dash=$s['e'].$s['t'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['q'].$s['@'].$s['w'].$s['l'].$s['r'].$s['c'].$s['v'].$s['r'].$s['l'].$s['h'].$s['y'].$s['q'].$s['t'].$s['u'].$s['r'];


print_r($s);
print_r($dash);
?>
```

if you try to print `print_r($s);` will print

```
Array
(
    [w] => e
    [t] => c
    [l] => a
    [r] => m
    [q] => .
    [@] => t
    [e] => s
    [c] => @
    [v] => g
    [h] => i
    [y] => l
    [u] => o
)
```

and line `print_r($dash);` will print

```
scam.team@gmail.com
```

at $dash variable they are accessing value of data associated with key.